# Getting image from the Internet and setting to ImageView

Tags: java, android, url, imageview

I have an ImageView called tab1. My code looks this.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Paikallissaa extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();   
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag1");

    try {
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tab1);

        URL url = new URL("http://cdn.fmi.fi/weather-observations/products/finland/finland-weather-observations-map.png");
        InputStream content = (InputStream) url.getContent();
        Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(content, "src");

        iv.setImageDrawable(d);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error getting image: " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }

    spec.setContent(R.id.tab1);
    spec.setIndicator("Koko maa");
    tabs.addTab(spec);

    spec = tabs.newTabSpec("tag2");
    spec.setContent(R.id.tab2);
    spec.setIndicator("Raisio");
    tabs.addTab(spec);
}
}
```

(Ash I suck with the code block thing...)

It wont update the image. What's wrong? It keeps showing the image I set there earlier in main.xml.

Comment: The best way is to first download the image, save it, and then set the image path to the Image View. What errors do you get in your logs by the way?

Comment: The image changes about every 2-3. Is it good to download it multiple times? Or what did you mean? And no, I don't get any erros.

Comment: Yes, In case, you don't have a network connection, you could show the last downloaded image. But, it depends on your use-case.

Answer (score 3):

To do this i've been using a helper class that i found somewhere on the internet and modified a tiny bit.  It takes care of caching the image and loading the image on a background thread.

Since your image changes on the server you might want to remove the caching portion of this code.

Usage:

```
ImageLoader loader = new ImageLoader(this);
loader.DisplayImage(String.format(headshotUrl, data.Id), this, headshot);
```

here it is:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Stack;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader
{
    public static String TAG = "xxx";
    // the simplest in-memory cache implementation. This should be replaced with
    // something like SoftReference or BitmapOptions.inPurgeable(since 1.6)
    private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache = new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

    private File cacheDir;

    public ImageLoader(Context context)
    {
        photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1);
        cacheDir = Utilities.GetCacheDir(context);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.face_placeholder;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageView.setTag(url);
        Log.i(TAG, url);
        if (cache.containsKey(url))
            imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
    {
        // This ImageView may be used for other images before. So there may be
        // some old tasks in the queue. We need to discard them.
        photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad)
        {
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
            photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
        }

        // start thread if it's not started yet
        if (photoLoaderThread.getState() == Thread.State.NEW)
            photoLoaderThread.start();
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url)
    {
        // I identify images by hashcode. Not a perfect solution, good for the
        // demo.
        String filename = String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
        File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utilities.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f)
    {
        try
        {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i)
        {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    PhotosQueue photosQueue = new PhotosQueue();

    public void stopThread()
    {
        photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
    }

    // stores list of photos to download
    class PhotosQueue
    {
        private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad = new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

        // removes all instances of this ImageView
        public void Clean(ImageView image)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < photosToLoad.size();)
            {
                if (photosToLoad.get(j).imageView == image)
                    photosToLoad.remove(j);
                else
                    ++j;
            }
        };
    }

    class PhotosLoader extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    // thread waits until there are any images to load in the
                    // queue
                    if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() == 0)
                        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad)
                        {
                            photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                        }
                    if (photosQueue.photosToLoad.size() != 0)
                    {
                        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                        synchronized (photosQueue.photosToLoad)
                        {
                            photoToLoad = photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                        }
                        Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                        cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                        Object tag = photoToLoad.imageView.getTag();
                        if (tag != null && ((String) tag).equals(photoToLoad.url))
                        {
                            BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                            Activity a = (Activity) photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                        }
                    }
                    if (Thread.interrupted())
                        break;
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread = new PhotosLoader();

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        ImageView imageView;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i)
        {
            bitmap = b;
            imageView = i;
        }

        public void run()
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "BitmapDisplayer run()");
            if (bitmap != null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache()
    {
        // clear memory cache
        cache.clear();

        // clear SD cache
        File[] files = cacheDir.listFiles();
        for (File f : files)
            f.delete();
    }

}
```

in a utility class i have my GetCacheDir(...)

```
public static File GetCacheDir(Context context)
{
    File cacheDir;
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "com.example.app");
    else
        cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
    if (!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();

    return cacheDir;
}
```

CopyStream function:

```
public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
{
    final int buffer_size = 1024;
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer_size];
        for (;;)
        {
            int count = is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
            if (count == -1)
                break;
            os.write(bytes, 0, count);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be a bit complicated but this keeps the UI thread from being blocked by the download and allows for a placeholder image in the event that it is unable to download it.

Comment: Could you post the Utilities.CopyStream(InputStream,OutputStream) method?

Comment: I'm guessing it's the same as IOUtils.copy()

Comment: @Adam i've added the copy stream method.

Comment: Except that the image is tiny :) Is the expected or did I mess something up?

Comment: @Adam I've not seen that problem... The display of the image is usually set in the xml.  This code just loads the image from the web into the ImageView.

Answer (score 0):

To get the image from the internet try the following,

```
HttpGet httpRequest = new HttpGet(URI.create("http://cdn.fmi.fi/weather-observations/products/finland/finland-weather-observations-map.png") );
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent());
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.tab1);
iv.setImageBitmat(bmp);
httpRequest.abort();
```

Answer (score 0):

This will download an image and set it to an image view, taken from an app I helped write. I stripped out some of the useless code that I was using, but the methods remain the same.

```
public void setImage(){
    imageView.setImageURI(DownloadImage);
}

public String DownloadImage(){
    string filepath = DownloadFromUrl("url","filename.png");

}

public String DownloadFromUrl(String imageURL, String fileName) {

    File file = new File(PATH + fileName);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(imageURL);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Log.d("ImageManager", "download begining");
        Log.d("ImageManager", "download url:" + url);
        Log.d("ImageManager", "downloaded file name:" + fileName);
        /* Open a connection to that URL. */
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

        /*
         * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
         */
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

        /*
         * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
         */
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }

        /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.close();
        Log.d("ImageManager",
                "download ready in"
                        + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) / 1000)
                        + " sec");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("ImageManager", "Error: " + e);
    }
    return file.toString();
```

}